# Animation is not starting

Tags: android, animation

i have this animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1600"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

And i want to start on a customview (Extending from ImageButton) click.

```
btnNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ReportListActivity.this, R.anim.rotatesync);
                anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
                btnNew.startAnimation(anim);
                btnNew.animate();
                DoSync.startSync(ReportListActivity.this);
            }
        });
```

But this code is executed but animation not..why?

Comment: It is all right with your code and animation xml. What is happening now?

Comment: Try to replace `btnNew.startAnimation(anim);
                btnNew.animate();` with `v.startAnimation(anim);v.animate();`